# Formatting data retrieved from asyncStorage in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

I am storing some data in `asyncStorage` via `@react-native-async-storage/async-storage` in my 'react-native' app. When I pull the data back out I want to assign the results to a drop-menu list, which expects this format:

```
names = [{name: 'Dave'}, {name: 'Julio'}];
```

Right now when I pull out the asyncStorage data, and apply `JSON.parse()`, it looks like this:

```
jsonNames:  Array [
  "{\"name\":\"Chris\"}",
  "{\"name\":\"Janet\"}",
  "{\"name\":\"Augustine\"}",
]
```

This is my function to retrieve the data:

```
  getNames = async () => {
    try {
      const jsonNames = await AsyncStorage.getItem('names')
      return jsonNames != null ? JSON.parse(jsonNames) : null;
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
```

Is there a function I can use to clean this up so that it's in the format I need, as described above?

Comment: Did you try using JSON.parse() ?

Comment: The above is the result of running JSON.parse().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to convert it do addition step like this

```js
const jsonNames = [
  "{\"name\":\"Chris\"}",
  "{\"name\":\"Janet\"}",
  "{\"name\":\"Augustine\"}",
];

console.log(jsonNames.map(x => JSON.parse(x)))
```

also, you can review the way you use to save this value in `AsyncStorage` it is look lik you serialize every object on array Separately before saving, not the whole array once.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're storing the data as JSON already and you could change that to avoid a new step parsing the JSON. In any case, if you want to work with the data as is, you could do this:

```
const jsonNames = [
  "{\"name\":\"Chris\"}",
  "{\"name\":\"Janet\"}",
  "{\"name\":\"Augustine\"}",
];
const names = jsonNames.map(JSON.parse)
```